# Writing differential equation for second order RC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, equation

I am trying to write an RC circuit's response in the form of a differential equation, but I can't find a solution and I haven't found a similar example on the internet. The circuit is as follows:

[image: RC Circuit]

I would like the final differential equation to be written only in terms of Vin and Vout. Currently my biggest issue is the node where R1, C1, and C2 are connected. I am unable to write this node in such a way that it only consists of variables Vout and Vin.

Comment: You could for instance replace \$V_{in}\$, \$R_1\$ and \$C_1\$ by their Thévenin equivalent circuit and you would then end up with a simple impedance divider to go to \$V_{out}\$. Then perhaps write in Laplace with \$s\$ and go to a differential equation then.

Comment: If initial conditions are zero, and Vin is a step, the problem is simplified - is that the case?

Comment: What have you already attempted. Show your work and ask a specific question so we can answer it

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I will later type up everything I tried until now, when I get the chance, as for the Thevenin equivalent method, I could do it but I would like to solve this problem only using the time domain.

Comment: @RikusCoetzee You will have two equations, not one, to be simultaneously solved. You can solve this in the Laplace domain, trivially, and then convert back to the time domain. Or you can solve it directly in the time domain. I'd like to see your approach, though. (Initial conditions may be required or simply left unspecified depending upon what you are after.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Maple sheet that can help you solve this problem.
By derivating and substitution ... you should obtain a single second-order equation to be solved.

It is not the "easy" way, and with Laplace functions, you can check your work.
Here is also the "brute force" formula, the answer is quasi "unreadable" ...

[image]

[image]

In the particular case where R1=R2=r and C1=C2=c, the solution is simpler ...

[image]

Easier when placing all numerical values and plotting ...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Call the junction of \$R_{1},C_{1},C_{2}\$ as Node a.

Apply nodal analysis.

Node a, by KCL:

$$\left[\frac{1}{R_{1}}+\left(C_{1}+C_{2}\right)\frac{d}{dt}\right]v_{a}(t)-\frac{1}{R_{1}}v_{in}(t)-C_{2}\frac{d}{dt}v_{out}(t)=0$$

The circuit is a band pass filter so the 1st derivative of the input is required.

So rearranging with the input on the right then taking the derivative produces.

$$\frac{1}{R_{1}}\frac{d}{dt}v_{a}(t)+\left(C_{1}+C_{2}\right)\frac{d}{dt}\frac{d}{dt}v_{a}(t)-C_{2}\frac{d}{dt}\frac{d}{dt}v_{out}(t)=\frac{1}{R_{1}}\frac{d}{dt}v_{in}(t)$$

Node out:

$$\left[C_{2}\frac{d}{dt}+\frac{1}{R_{2}}\right]v_{out}(t)=C_{2}\frac{d}{dt}v_{a}(t)$$

Dividing by \$C_{2}\$:

$$\left[\frac{d}{dt}v_{out}(t)+\frac{1}{R_{2}C_{2}}v_{out}(t)\right]=\frac{d}{dt}v_{a}(t)$$

Substitute:

$$\frac{1}{R_{1}}\left[\frac{d}{dt}v_{out}(t)+\frac{1}{R_{2}C_{2}}v_{out}(t)\right]+\left(C_{1}+C_{2}\right)\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{d}{dt}v_{out}(t)+\frac{1}{R_{2}C_{2}}v_{out}(t)\right]-C_{2}\frac{d}{dt}\frac{d}{dt}v_{out}(t)=\frac{1}{R_{1}}\frac{d}{dt}v_{in}(t)$$

Expanding and collecting terms:

$$\frac{d^{2}}{dt^{2}}v_{out}(t)+\left(\frac{1}{C_{1}R_{1}}+\frac{1}{R_{2}C_{1}}+\frac{1}{R_{2}C_{2}}\right)\frac{d}{dt}v_{out}(t)+\frac{1}{R_{1}R_{2}C_{1}C_{2}}v_{out}(t)=\frac{1}{R_{1}C_{1}}\frac{d}{dt}v_{in}(t)$$